# How to set the area of a circlemarker as proportional to an attribute value?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, area

So I am making a Leaflet map. I am using a json which lists countries as Latlng points, and their corresponding attribute (called CTH values). I am trying to use this value to set the area of circle markers on these Latlng points to be proportional to the CTH value, but I am struggling to figure out how.

This is what I've written

```
    function addCTHValueMarkers () {

       CTHValueLayer = L.geoJSON(CTHValue,  {
                    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                        return new L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                        fillOpacity: 0.6,
                        radius: setRadius(feature.properties.CTHValue)
                       })
                    }
    });

   CTHValueLayer.addTo(map);
   }
```

I was originally going to use the radius but I need area to make them actually proportional, can someone show me how I set the area? Do I make a seperate function to work out area, then pass this to the radius? How do I do this?

Whenever I try to refer to (feature.properties.CTHValue) outside of the CTHValueLayer = L.geojson(CTHValue { }) argument it doesn't work, can someone show me how I can access the CTH Value from within my geojson in a seperate function, so I can pass the CTHValue to an area calculation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the radius of a circle marker to be proportional to an attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401891/how-to-set-the-radius-of-a-circle-marker-to-be-proportional-to-an-attribute-valu)

Comment: no :( i now know i have to use area not radius, but idk how to do that either.

Comment: im trying to do it like this: function updatePropSymbols() {
   
    var props = (feature.properties.CTHValue);  
    var radius = setRadius(props); 
   
  }
   
  function setRadius(props) {
     
   var scaleFactor = 0.01;
   
   var area = props * scaleFactor;
    
   return Math.sqrt(area / Math.PI);
  
  }

but I get an error in the console saying "feature is undefined" i think its bc its in a seperate function to my initialising the json so it doesnt recognise feature.properties.CTHValue. so how do i pass the CTH value from my json into the radius function?

Comment: Hey, please stop with the duplicate questions! I think you're up to 6 now on this one problem.

Comment: well im stuck and was told to use this forum when im stuck?? im on a deadline. i have tried to do it myself and updated each time with what ive tried to do. i cannot move on until ive done this and i urgently need to move on

Comment: I think time has come to point you towards https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (do divide-and-conquer, e.g. does it work with a constant radius?; work on creating a working example *once*, and *edit* a question to update it instead of asking six times) and http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent (in particular, your deadline is *your* problem; volume doesn't equal value)

Answer (score -1):

So probably you need to use `L.circle` instead `L.circleMarker`.
Because `circleMarker` it's a Marker and doesn't have size

Comment: No; both `L.Circle`s and `L.CircleMarker`s have a `radius` (the former in meters, and the later in CSS pixels)